# CheckBox in ComboBox

Tags: qooxdoo

I would like to have checkBoxes inside a comboBox, like in this simplified example :

```
var rawData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    rawData.push(i);;
}  
var data = new qx.data.Array(rawData);

var list = new qx.ui.form.ComboBox();
list.setWidth(150);

this.getRoot().add(list);

var controller = new qx.data.controller.List(null, list);

var delegate = {
    createItem : function() {
    return new qx.ui.form.CheckBox();
    }
};

controller.setDelegate(delegate);

controller.setModel(data);
```

It's working but i'm not able to "check" the checkboxes because the combobox is closed when i click on it, so i would like to open/close the combobox only with the button. 
How to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some event of the ComboBox is responsible for closing the PopUp (see [code on GitHub](https://github.com/qooxdoo/qooxdoo/blob/master/framework/source/class/qx/ui/form/AbstractSelectBox.js#L215)) before the click can get to an underlying checkbox. If you implement your own ComboBox and overwrite the close method it works.

```
qx.Class.define("foo.ComboBox", {
  extend: qx.ui.form.ComboBox,
  members: {
    close: function() {
    }
  }
})

var rawData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    rawData.push(i);;
}  
var data = new qx.data.Array(rawData);

var list = new foo.ComboBox();
list.setWidth(150);

var controller = new qx.data.controller.List(null, list);
var delegate = {
    createItem : function() {
    return new qx.ui.form.CheckBox();
    }
};
controller.setDelegate(delegate);
controller.setModel(data);

this.getRoot().add(list);
```

However now you have to think about how you will handle multiple selection of checkboxes and when to close the popup.